# Elasticsearch match with stemming

Tags: search, elasticsearch, stem

How do I do a search for a stemmed match?

I.e. at the moment I have many documents that contain the word "skateboard" in the `item_title` field, but only 3 documents that contain the word "skateboards". Because of this, when I do the following search:

```
POST /my_index/my_type/_search
{
    "size": 100,
    "query" : {
        "multi_match": {
           "query": "skateboards",
           "fields": [ "item_title^3" ]
        }
    }
}
```

I only get 3 results. However, I would like also documents with the word "skateboard" to be returned.

From what I understand from Elasticsearch I would expect that this is done by specifying a mapping on the `item_title` field that contains an analyser which indexes the stemmed version of each word, but I can't seem to find the documentation on how to do this, which suggests that it's done in a different way.

Suggestions?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Here's one example:

```
PUT /stem
{
  "settings": {
    "analysis": {
      "filter": {
        "filter_stemmer": {
          "type": "stemmer",
          "language": "english"
        }
      },
      "analyzer": {
        "tags_analyzer": {
          "type": "custom",
          "filter": [
            "standard",
            "lowercase",
            "filter_stemmer"
          ],
          "tokenizer": "standard"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "mappings": {
    "test": {
      "properties": {
        "item_title": {
          "analyzer": "tags_analyzer",
          "type": "text"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Index some sample docs:

```
POST /stem/test/1
{
  "item_title": "skateboards"
}
POST /stem/test/2
{
  "item_title": "skateboard"
}
POST /stem/test/3
{
  "item_title": "skate"
}
```

Perform the query:

```
GET /stem/test/_search
{
  "query": {
    "multi_match": {
      "query": "skateboards",
      "fields": [
        "item_title^3"
      ]
    }
  },
  "fielddata_fields": [
    "item_title"
  ]
}
```

And see the results:

```
  "hits": [
     {
        "_index": "stem",
        "_type": "test",
        "_id": "1",
        "_score": 1,
        "_source": {
           "item_title": "skateboards"
        },
        "fields": {
           "item_title": [
              "skateboard"
           ]
        }
     },
     {
        "_index": "stem",
        "_type": "test",
        "_id": "2",
        "_score": 1,
        "_source": {
           "item_title": "skateboard"
        },
        "fields": {
           "item_title": [
              "skateboard"
           ]
        }
     }
  ]
```

I have added, also, the `fielddata_fields` element so that you can see how the content of the field has been indexed. As you can see, in both cases, the indexed term is `skateboard`.

Comment: Wanted to point out that `"type": "string"` in `mappings` should be `"type": "text"` if you are using a newer version of Elasticsearch (https://stackoverflow.com/a/47454366/1067590)