# No handler for type [string] declared on field [name]

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-mapping, elasticsearch-6

When `type` is declared as `string`, Elasticsearch 6.0 will show this error.

```
"name" => [
  "type" => "string",
  "analyzer" => "ik_max_word"
]
```

Comment: There is no field type "string", i think you you mean "text"?

Comment: I am migrating es2 to es6, it seems "string"  is removed  .thanks,

Comment: Yes, see https://www.elastic.co/blog/strings-are-dead-long-live-strings

Answer (score 267):

Elasticsearch has dropped the `string` type and is now using `text`. So your code should be something like this

```
"name" => [
  "type" => "text",
  "analyzer" => "ik_max_word"
]
```

Comment: Also if you have error with :uuid, than change 'string' to 'keyword'.